# $f$ is continuous and $f(V)$ is open whenever $V$ is open $\implies$ $f$ is monotone

Tags: continuity

Let $ A $ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ and $f : A \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function on $A$ such that $f(V)$ is an open set for any open set $V$ , then how to prove that $f$ is monotone ?

Comment: I think you should assume that $A$ is connected. Consider $f(x) = x$ for $x ∈ (0, 1)$ and $f(x) = -x$ for $x ∈ (1, 2)$ otherwise.

Comment: This will help http://wj32.org/wp/2013/01/15/every-continuous-open-mapping-of-r-into-r-is-monotonic/

Answer (score 3):

One method:

Suppose $A$ is connected (otherwise, the statement isn't generally true).

If $f$ is continuous but not monotonic, there exists $a,b,c \in A$ with $[a,c] \subset A$ and $f(a) = f(c) < f(b)$ or $f(a) = f(c) > f(b)$ (verify that this must be the case).  Show that 
$f((a,c))$
cannot be open (hint: why does $f$ attain a maximum/minimum on $(a,c)$?).

Thus, $f$ not monotonic $\implies$ $f(V)$ is not always open for open $V$.  The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

As you hace been said, we need to assume that $A$ is connected. Then, it is possible to assume WOLOG that $V$ is connected, hence, $f(V)$ is connected.

Suppose that $f(V)$ is not open. Then, there exists some $y\in f(V)$ (say, $f(x)=y$) such that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $y_\epsilon\in(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$. Therefore, $\sup$ or $\inf f(V)=y$, that is, $f$ meets an extremus at $x$.